# Why doesn't `scalaVersion in Global` set scalaVersion for all projects?

Tags: scala, sbt

After reading [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html) documentation, I expected

```
scalaVersion in Global := "2.10.3"
```

in `object MyProjectBuild extends Build` to set `scalaVersion` for all projects. However, after reloading the project, I get

```
> show scalaVersion
[info] subproject1/*:scalaVersion
[info]  2.10.2
[info] subproject2/*:scalaVersion
[info]  2.10.2
[info] all/*:scalaVersion
[info]  2.10.2
```

Same happens with `ThisBuild` instead of `Global`. `scalaVersion` isn't set anywhere else. What am I misunderstanding? `inspect` produces (both for `Global` and `ThisBuild`):

```
> inspect scalaVersion
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 2.10.2
[info] Description:
[info]  The version of Scala used for building.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:211
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  all/*:ivyReport::update
[info]  all/*:dependencyUpdatesData
[info]  all/*:scalaInstance
[info]  all/*:update
[info]  all/*:allDependencies
[info]  all/*:libraryDependencies
[info] Delegates:
[info]  all/*:scalaVersion
[info]  {.}/*:scalaVersion
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
> inspect actual scalaVersion
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 2.10.2
[info] Description:
[info]  The version of Scala used for building.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:211
[info] Delegates:
[info]  all/*:scalaVersion
[info]  {.}/*:scalaVersion
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
```

I currently set common settings for all projects using a `val commonSettings = Seq(scalaVersion := ...)` and `settings(commonSettings: _*)` for all projects, so the question is specifically why doesn't the above approach work.

Comment: Did you try `inspect scalaVersion` and `inspect actual scalaVersion` for hints on where it is getting the value from?

Comment: @huynhjl Added the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project was using SBT 0.13.0. After switching to 0.13.1 it works as expected, though I don't see anything relevant in the [changelog](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Community/Changes.html).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're using the Play Framework or some other framework that adds its own keys to the build, and you're setting the scala version before adding the framework keys.

Move the `scalaVersion` definition to the bottom of the build script, you should get what you want (or, alternatively, move the `playScalaSettings` or whatever else above the definition)

Comment: No, I am not using any such framework. I was setting `scalaVersion` early in `Build.scala`, but moving `scalaVersion` to the bottom doesn't change anything.